# How to access data attributes in Framework7 Preprocess

Tags: html-framework-7

I am loading dynamic pages with F7 preprocess and T7. I am having some difficulties to access product ID stored in data attribute. The thing is that I want when the user clicks a product in the product catalog; the detail page loads with details of the clicked product. But whenever I am trying this I am getting undefined for var id. here is my code:

**HTML**
***show.html***

```
{{#each this}}
       <div class="content-block"><!--Block Content-->
         <div class="row"> <!--Block Content row-->
               <div class="col-25">
                  <a href="show.html" class="link" data-id={{id}}>
               <div class="item-media"><img src="{{product_image}}" width="100" height="100"></div>
            </a>
               <h3>{{product_name}}</h3>
                  <div class="chip"> 
             <div class="chip-label">KES.{{price}}</div> 
                        </div>
               <p>{{product_desc}}</p>
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-50">
                     <a href="#" class="button button-small button-fill color-blue">Add to Cart</a></div> 


                   <div class="col-50">

                     <a href="#" class="button button-small button-fill color-gray">Add to Wishlist</a></div> 
                  </div>
                  </div>
```

**myApp.js**

```
var myApp = new Framework7({

        template7Pages: true, // enable Template7 rendering for Ajax and Dynamic pages
         animateNavBackIcon: true,
           // Enabled rendering pages using Template7
   template7Pages: true,
  precompileTemplates: true,

    preprocess: function (content, url, next) {
      var rootUrl = 'http://localhost/phonestore/public/api/';
      switch(url)
      {
case 'show.html':
         var id = $$(this).attr('data-id');
       //alert(id) returns undefined


         //Fetch product categories and display them in list box
         var serverUrl = rootUrl+'products/'+id;
         $$.ajax({
    url: serverUrl,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

   var compiled = Template7.compile(content);
            next(compiled(data));


    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("ERROR: " + errorThrown)
    }
});

         break;
.....
}
}
```

All data is coming from the server. How can I fetch product id attribute in preprocess. Please assist.

Comment: `data-id` is an attribute in ` show.html` file ?

Comment: Yes, its an attribute in show.html. I have just edited the post to indicate this.

Comment: Thanks for presicion. One more thing, you don't have two pages ? (1 for list, one for detail)

Comment: The product catalog page lists all products. when the user clicks on a product thumbnail is when is led to show.html with full  details of the clicked item.

Answer (score 0):

F7 documentation says on `preprocess`:

> Framework7 allows you to use your favorite client-side template engine or do any modifications with loaded content.

You don't have to pass by preprocess to do that.

First, remove href on `a` tag and add it a class (`go-detail` for example)

Then add an event listener on list items :

```
$$('.content-block a.go-detail').on('click', function(event) {
    var itemId = $$(event.target).attr('data-id');
    //do ajax call to retrieve data and load show.html page !
});
```

I think this is a simplier solution thn pass by `preprocess` method.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However removing href attribute from <a> elements renders unclickable. I have also kept the href attribute with # but still clicking the thumbnail does not trigger any event. The console show no error. <div class="content-block"><!--Block Content-->
         <div class="row"> <!--Block Content row-->
               <div class="col-25">
                  <a href="#" class="go-detail" data-id={{id}}>
               <div class="item-media"><img src="{{product_image}}" width="100" height="100"></div>
            </a>.........

Comment: Also I am not sure how I will pass from the server to show.html using this method just incase it works. Its like only preprocess supports server data.

Comment: 1) Yes you have to keep href attr with "#" value
2) Otherwise keep preprocess logic. You have just to save `data-id` in global variable to get it in preprocess

Answer (score 0):

you can use this approach:
populating var trashIcon and composeIcon:

```
app.on('pageInit', function (e, page) {
                var ios = this.theme.ios;
                var trashIcon = ios ? '<i class="icon f7-icons">trash</i>' : '<i class="icon material-icons">delete</i>';
                var composeIcon = ios ? '<i class="icon f7-icons">compose</i>' : '<i class="icon material-icons">edit</i>';
            });
```

and to load those JavaScript variables: don't used {{trashIcon}} but used + trashIcon +

`$.each(bookingsData, function (index, onedata) {
                    bookingdatahtml = bookingdatahtml 
                        + '<tr>'
                        + '<td class="actions-cell"><a class="link icon-only" onclick="EditThis(' + onedata.bookings_id + ')" href="javascript:void(0)">' + composeIcon + '</a>'
                        + '<a class="link icon-only" onclick="DeleteThis(' + onedata.bookings_id + ')" href="javascript:void(0)">' + trashIcon + '</a>'
                        + '</td >'
                        + '</tr>'
                }); 
$$('#showBookingbyUserId').html(bookingdatahtml);`